# Avoiding paste values on different dropdown excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to have an Excel file with some columns that have dropdown and I would to avoid people to copy and paste in those columns. But if the value they are pasting is correct then they can paste.

The code I have is working for one column. I am trying to do for multiple columns with different dropdowns each one.

In this code example it is just for two columns (C and D) with the dropdowns in sheet "dropdowns" in columns A and B respectively.

Any help on how to modify the code below to make it work for more columns?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim isect As Range
Dim isect2 As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim dd() As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim mtch As Boolean
Dim msg As String
Dim myEntries As String
Dim ddRange As Range
Dim ddRange2 As Range


Set rng1 = Range("C:C")
Set rng2 = Range("D:D")

Set ddRange = Sheets("Dropdowns").Range("A2:A11")
Set ddRange2 = Sheets("Dropdowns").Range("B2:B8")




Set isect = Intersect(rng1, Target)

Set isect2 = Intersect(rng2, Target)


If (isect Is Nothing) And (isect2 Is Nothing) Then Exit Sub

Application.EnableEvents = False



If Not isect Is Nothing Then

    ReDim dd(ddRange.Cells.Count)
    i = 0
    For Each cell In ddRange
        dd(i) = cell.Value
        i = i + 1
    Next cell


    For Each cell In isect

        mtch = False
        For i = LBound(dd) To UBound(dd)
            If cell.Value = dd(i) Then
                mtch = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i

        If mtch = False Then
            cell.ClearContents
            msg = msg & cell.Address(0, 0) & ","
        End If
    Next cell



    For i = LBound(dd) To UBound(dd)
        myEntries = myEntries & dd(i) & ","
    Next i
    myEntries = Left(myEntries, Len(myEntries) - 1)


    With rng1.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:=myEntries
    End With


    If Len(msg) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Invalid entries in cells: " & vbCrLf & Left(msg, Len(msg) - 1), vbOKOnly, "ERROR!"
    End If
End If



If Not isect2 Is Nothing Then

    For Each cell In isect2
        If (Len(cell) > 0) And (Len(cell) <> 11) Then
            cell.ClearContents
            msg = msg & cell.Address(0, 0) & ","
        End If
    Next cell


    With rng2.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateTextLength, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="11"
    End With


    If Len(msg) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Invalid entries in cells: " & vbCrLf & Left(msg, Len(msg) - 1), vbOKOnly, "ERROR!"
    End If
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

I was thinking trying to create a Function and every column with a dropdown to call that function with the corresponding correct dropdowns.

Is this a correct approach? Any help on this?

Thank you in advance for your time!!

Answer (score 0):

What about this? It's kind of dirty, but it's really useful.

Let's say you want to avoid people pasting values in any cell of 2 specific columns (in my case it would be any cell of columns C or D). For that I use:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column = 3 Or Target.Column = 4 Then Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

So if user copies a cell into clipboard, and then selects a cell in column C or D, the clipboard will empty, so they can't paste anything.

You can customize the conditions to check this and be more restrictive (only a specific range, a table, a group of cells, and so on). My example is the easy one.

You can combine this with normal dropwdowns provided by data validations in cells, so they cannot paste anything in those cells.

I know this may look dirty and tricky, but it works awesome at my office with some teammates in specific forms.

Comment: Well, may be a solution but it is not what I was looking for. Since I want to show a MsgBox when they are trying to copy and with this method the message will show every time you click on the cells. Also, if the value they are trying to copy is correct I want that they are aviable to copy. Thank you!!